# Split array into weeks?

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am returning an array from a database which contains a date field. I would like to split the array into weeks for example 'this week', 'next week'.

A lot of the examples I can find online are relative to today's date which is not what I want.

Today is 06/05/15, so this week started 01/05/15 and ends 07/05/15 .. I want to pluck out all entries that fall between these dates into their own array. Next week starts on 08/05/15 and ends 14/05/15, I want to pluck all dates that feel between these dates into a separate array.

Comment: No code unfortunately, the few things I tried didn't work.. wasn't hoping someone would write it for me just pointing in the right direction to get the proper values for week starting and end dates... the few examples i have tried have been relative to todays, i.e. todays date +/-6 .

Comment: What format is the date field in the array?

Comment: MYSQL DATETIME 1970-01-01 00:00:01

Comment: I'm not sure why this thread is being downvoted so much, although I would say it would be of benefit to everyone if you posted an sample of your result set. I assume the dates are not contiguous, and there might be gaps?

Comment: A question, if are you going to actually use the terminology "this week", "next week" and so on: if you have more than two weeks of results to group, what are you going to call the subsequent weeks? I would imagine "the week after", "the week after that" and so on would not be a sustainable approach!

Comment: It's basically a list of events that take place on certain dates.. start_date contains MYSQL DATE.. the returned array needs splitting into categories based on start_date ('this week', 'next week' and then 'upcoming' (i.e. anything after 'next week')).. to achieve this i need to get the current week (mon-sun) regardless of what day of the week it is and so on..

Comment: Cool. If you post an example of the result set I'll have a go at an answer a little later.

Comment: Additionally, you say `start_date` contains a MySQL formatted date - I assume this is **Y-m-d** format; e.g: `2015-06-07`. Also, are you starting the week on a Sunday, or Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are grouping your result set into three categories - *This week*, *Next week* and *Upcoming* - you just need to know is the start of the next week and the week after. You can then iterate over your result set, compare and group accordingly.

Judging from your comments above you are starting the week on Monday, so:

```
$dateTime       = new DateTime('next monday');
$weekStartNext  = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$weekStartAfter = $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You now have ISO8601 format datetime strings for the next Monday and the Monday after. So, given a result set like this:

```
$rows = [
    [
        'name'       => 'Sunday 7th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-07 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Monday 8th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-08 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Friday 12th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-12 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Sunday 14th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-14 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Monday 15th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-15 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Sunday 21st June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-21 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Tuesday 30th June',
        'start_date' => '2015-06-30 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name'       => 'Wednesday 1st July',
        'start_date' => '2015-07-01 00:00:00',
    ],
];
```

You can do simple string comparison on the row dates, like so:

```
$sorted = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $startDate = $row['start_date'];

    if ($startDate < $weekStartNext) {
        $sorted['This week'][] = $row;
    } elseif ($startDate >= $weekStartNext && $startDate < $weekStartAfter) {
        $sorted['Next week'][] = $row;
    } else {
        $sorted['Upcoming'][] = $row;
    }
}

print_r($sorted);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [This week] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sunday 7th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-07 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [Next week] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Monday 8th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-08 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Friday 12th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-12 00:00:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sunday 14th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-14 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [Upcoming] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Monday 15th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-15 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sunday 21st June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-21 00:00:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Tuesday 30th June
                    [start_date] => 2015-06-30 00:00:00
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Wednesday 1st July
                    [start_date] => 2015-07-01 00:00:00
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a starting point to detect if a given unix date `$date` is within this week:

```
if (($date >= strtotime('monday this week')) and ($date <= strtotime('sunday this week'))) {
    // $date is within this week
}
```

Relevant documentation: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Adding helpful links to relevant docs as well as a brief explanation would improve this answer.